# pySHACL: failure to report validation errors

Tags: python, validation, rdf, rdflib, shacl

I have a gist with all of the relevant files at: https://gist.github.com/James-Hudson3010/2588d9b17dd33e15922122b8b5cf1bd7

If I execute:

```
$ pyshacl -a -f human employees.ttl
```

I get the following, correct validation report...

```
Validation Report
Conforms: False
Results (3):
Constraint Violation in MaxInclusiveConstraintComponent (http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#MaxInclusiveConstraintComponent):
    Severity: sh:Violation
    Source Shape: hr:jobGradeShape
    Focus Node: d:e4
    Value Node: Literal("8", datatype=xsd:integer)
    Result Path: hr:jobGrade
Constraint Violation in DatatypeConstraintComponent (http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#DatatypeConstraintComponent):
    Severity: sh:Violation
    Source Shape: hr:jobGradeShape
    Focus Node: d:e3
    Value Node: Literal("3.14", datatype=xsd:decimal)
    Result Path: hr:jobGrade
Constraint Violation in MinCountConstraintComponent (http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#MinCountConstraintComponent):
    Severity: sh:Violation
    Source Shape: hr:jobGradeShape
    Focus Node: d:e2
    Result Path: hr:jobGrade
```

However, if I split employees.ttl into three files containing the schema, shape, and instance data and run:

```
pyshacl -s shape.ttl -e schema.ttl -a -f human instance.ttl
```

the result is:

```
Validation Report
Conforms: True
```

I assume I am calling pyshacl correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the individual files, pySHACL has no way of knowing what to associate your Shape file's `hr:Employee` NodeShape with. It seems to know when it's in that single file (perhaps it runs against all classes in the file??).

So:

1. rename the Employee shape to not overload the `hr:Employee` class name: `hr:EmployeeShape`
2. add back in the `sh:targetClass` directive:

```
hr:EmployeeShape
   a sh:NodeShape ;
   sh:targetClass hr:Employee ;
   sh:property hr:nameShape ;
   sh:property hr:jobGradeShape .
```

Then the multi-file call gives the same result as the single file call.

Your calls to pySHACL are correct!

Comment: Nick, to answer your question regarding how does it know how to handle a single file;  if only a monlithic datafile is given to pyshacl, it simply clones that graph (before any inferencing) and that cloned graph is used as the SHACL Shapes graph. That way any Shapes in the monolithic file will be used correctly.

Comment: For some additional information, see https://github.com/RDFLib/pySHACL/issues/46

Comment: How can I use these Three separate files in Python Module?